# conditional types using generics in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Note: I have a working solution for this problem, but I am hoping somebody may be able to show me a more efficient and compact way to implement it.

Problem:

I have a react component like so:

```
function Component({ idIdentifier = "id", nameIdentifier = "name", persons }) { // render
```

the idea is that the **persons** prop should be an array of object(s) that match the identifiers specified in the **idIdentifier** and **nameIdentifier** props, for example using default prop values it should look like:

```
persons = [ { id: "1", name: "Joe" } ]
```

I want to make this component more powerful by adding type specification using TypeScript. I need the specification to be sophisticated enough so it can flag errors when the following occurs:

**when using Component type of *persons* prop being passed in does not match specification when:**

- **idIdentifier** and **nameIdentifier** props not passed, default values used
- Custom value for **idIdentifier** prop passed and
  **nameIdentifier** prop not passed, default value used for latter
- Custom value for **nameIdentifier** prop passed and
  **idIdentifier** prop not passed, default value used for latter
- Custom value for both **nameIdentifier** and
  **idIdentifier** props passed

Below is my solution:

```
const ID = 'id'
const NAME = 'name'

type Id = typeof ID
type Name = typeof NAME

type Persons<T1 extends string, T2 extends string> = { [key in (T1 | T2)]: string }[]

type VariableProps<T1, T2> = {
  idIdentifier?: T1
  nameIdentifier?: T2
}

type DefaultProps = {
  persons: Persons<Id, Name>
} & VariableProps<Id, Name>

type PropsWithName<T extends string> = {
  idIdentifier?: Id
  nameIdentifier: T
  persons: Persons<Id, T>
}

type PropsWithId<T extends string> = {
  idIdentifier: T
  nameIdentifier?: Name
  persons: Persons<T, Name>
}

type PropsWithIdAndName<T1 extends string, T2 extends string> = {
  persons: Persons<T1, T2>
} & Required<VariableProps<T1, T2>>

type AllProps<T1 extends string, T2 extends string> = (DefaultProps | PropsWithName<T1> | PropsWithId<T2> | PropsWithIdAndName<T1, T2>)

function Component<T1 extends string, T2 extends string>({ idIdentifier = ID, nameIdentifier = NAME, persons }: AllProps<T1, T2>) { // render
```

Example usages:

```
<Component options={[{ id: "1", name: "Joe" }]} /> // TS happy
<Component options={[{ id: "1", nickName: "Joe" }]} /> // TS sad
<Component nameIdentifier="nickName" options={[{ id: "1", nickName: "Joe" }]} /> // TS happy
<Component nameIdentifier="nickName" options={[{ id: "1", name: "Joe" }]} /> // TS sad
<Component nameIdentifier="nickName" idIdentifier="value" options={[{ id: "1", nickName: "Joe" }]} /> // TS sad
<Component nameIdentifier="nickName" idIdentifier="value" options={[{ value: "1", nickName: "Joe" }]} /> // TS happy
```

My solution does work and it will give me the warnings I need under all scenarios when there is a mismatch, but I wondered if my code could be more compact, the real world Component has more moving parts and this approach has doubled the length of the file.

Any feedback greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'd willing to bet that there is some pattern in the requirements. How much more moving part do you have in your component?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAv0vW) example helps